# Get Specific Key with Highest Value from a (JSON) Object

Tags: javascript, json

I'm getting data back from an API response and attempting to get the name of the pitch with the highest speed. Here is a sample of the API response.

```
{
page: 1,
total_pages: 4,
listings: [
    {
        name: "A.J. Burnett",
        pitches: [
            {
                name: "4 Seam FB",
                speed: 96,
                control: 84,
            },
            {
                name: "Knuckle Curve",
                speed: 79,
                control: 74,
            },
            {
                name: "Sinker",
                speed: 95,
                control: 64,
            },
            {
                name: "Changeup",
                speed: 81,
                control: 44,
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: "Joe Smitch",
        pitches: [
            {
                name: "4 Seam FB",
                speed: 91,
                control: 82,
            },
            {
                name: "Changeup",
                speed: 69,
                control: 44,
            }
        ]
    },
]
}
```

Here is what I've tried:

```
itemSet.forEach( (item) => {
    let fastestPitch = Object.keys(item.pitches).reduce((a, b) => {
        item.pitches[a] > item.pitches[b] ? item.pitches[a].name : item.pitches[b].name
     });
});
```

However, this always returns the name of the LAST pitch in the array. I'm attempting to return the pitch with the highest speed.

Edit: I've also tried the following, but it returns an error.

```
itemSet.forEach( (item) => {
    let fastestPitch = Object.keys(item.pitches).reduce((a, b) => {
        item.pitches[a].speed > item.pitches[b].speed ? item.pitches[a].name : item.pitches[b].name
     });
});
```

Error:

```
(node:80698) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'speed' of undefined
```

Comment: `item.pitches[a] > item.pitches[b]` will compare the *objects*, not the `speed` property of the objects.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `item.pitches[a].speed > item.pitches[b].speed` ?

Comment: @PeterB that gives me the following error: ```(node:80698) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'speed' of undefined```

Comment: Ugh, it's because in the second iteration, you only have a name as string as `a`

Comment: Isn't `pitches` and array and if so, why are you using `Object.keys(item.pitches)` ?

Comment: `reduce()` should always return either `a` or `b`, but you are returning something entirely different that is derived from a or b.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```js
const data = {
  page: 1,
  total_pages: 4,
  listings: [{
      name: "A.J. Burnett",
      pitches: [{
          name: "4 Seam FB",
          speed: 96,
          control: 84,
        },
        {
          name: "Knuckle Curve",
          speed: 79,
          control: 74,
        },
        {
          name: "Sinker",
          speed: 95,
          control: 64,
        },
        {
          name: "Changeup",
          speed: 81,
          control: 44,
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: "Joe Smitch",
      pitches: [{
          name: "4 Seam FB",
          speed: 91,
          control: 82,
        },
        {
          name: "Changeup",
          speed: 69,
          control: 44,
        }
      ]
    },
  ]
}

const fastesPitches = data.listings.map(({ pitches }) => {
  return pitches.reduce((a, c) => c.speed > a.speed ? c : a).name;
});

console.log(fastesPitches);
```

Answer (score 1):

To extract the fastest of each, you can `Array#map` each of the entries in `listings` and then `Array#reduce` their entries in `pitches` like this:

```js
let data = { page: 1, total_pages: 4, listings: [{ name: "A.J. Burnett", pitches: [{ name: "4 Seam FB", speed: 96, control: 84, }, { name: "Knuckle Curve", speed: 79, control: 74, }, { name: "Sinker", speed: 95, control: 64, }, { name: "Changeup", speed: 81, control: 44, } ] }, { name: "Joe Smitch", pitches: [{ name: "4 Seam FB", speed: 91, control: 82, }, { name: "Changeup", speed: 69, control: 44, } ] }, ] };

let fastestPitches = data.listings.map(obj => {
  return obj.pitches.reduce((best, current) => {
    return best.speed > current.speed ? best : current
  }, {}).name
});

console.log(fastestPitches)
```

Note that when you reduce, the first argument (`best`, in this case) is the result of the *previous* callback. So if you return just the name, you won't know what the speed of it was. So, you traverse and compare the speeds, then return the entire object that was better. When this finishes, you get the `name` of the result.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a complete dynamic approach which looks for any depth and return the object with the wanted highest property from the most nested objects.

```js
function getHighest(object, key) {
    return Object.values(object).reduce((r, o) => {
        if (!o || typeof o !== 'object') return r;
        if (key in o && (!r || r[key] < o[key])) return o;
        var temp = getHighest(o, key);
        if (temp && (!r || r[key] < temp[key])) return temp;
        return r;
    }, undefined);
}

var data = { page: 1, total_pages: 4, listings: [{ name: "A.J. Burnett", pitches: [{ name: "4 Seam FB", speed: 96, control: 84 }, { name: "Knuckle Curve", speed: 79, control: 74 }, { name: "Sinker", speed: 95, control: 64 }, { name: "Changeup", speed: 81, control: 44 }] }, { name: "Joe Smitch", pitches: [{ name: "4 Seam FB", speed: 91, control: 82 }, { name: "Changeup", speed: 69, control: 44 }] }] },
    highest = getHighest(data, 'speed');

console.log(highest.name);
console.log(highest);
```